# Can I ferment pickles in the tropics?

Tags: food-safety, temperature, food-preservation, pickles

I live in the tropics where the temperature mostly ranges from 28 to 33 degrees Celsius (82 to 91 Fahrenheit) or higher.

I want to try my hand at fermented pickles but most sources seem to claim that 77 deg Fahrenheit is the maximum.  Does that mean that there is no point in trying?

Comment: What kind of pickle recipe, from what region? Certain pickle recipes (indian achar style) come with the express suggestion to let it ferment straight in direct sunlight...

Comment: Kimchi (Korean pickled cabbage) direct storage in a refrigerator but the traditional method was to bury it in the 'cool earth' (down about 4 feet or 1 meter) if refrigeration isn't an option for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ferment in a cool place, so you can only ferment pickles in the monsoon season when temperatures are down, or inside a house with A.C.

Vegetables turn soft if it's too hot. Taste and feel is important here. Soft vegetables are the biggest problem if it's too hot. On the 3rd day it is good to place in the fridge to slow the fermenting, if you can.

Crocks may be wrapped in burlap, palm  dry, & kept wet in a cool shade place with breeze. Cloudy days are a big help. Place a plate on top of crock to keep insects dirt out. So it can be done with care. I'm in the South Phillipines, and it seems to work on the shady side of the house under the second floor A.C., where dripwater hits a wrapped crock, along with the breeze in the monsoon season.

Comment: I tried to edit this to clarify. The one thing I couldn't understand was "palm dry" - what does that refer to? Could you please edit to clarify?